# Configurable products from XML

Tags: csv

So i'm importing products from .csv file. The file I want to import is located here https://en.yournewstyle.pl/tresc/csv-files (it says it's configured for magento). Import goes fine, but all products are imported as configurable products. Is that import file fault or I just don't get it how to configure them right? From what I understand I need simple products linked to the configurable products is that right?

Answer (score 2):

The CSV file (https://yournewstyle.pl/iof/magento.en.csv) looks okay, it contains simple and configurable products. But: it won't import completely if the setup of your store is not correct:

- It requires an attribute "size" with options like S, M, L, XL
- It should have an attribute "color" which is either a text field or a dropdown field with all values which appear in the "color" column in the csv file
- It expects the website code to be "base"
- It expects an attribute set named "Default"
- It probably won't import product images for simple products as the column values for `_media_attribute_id` and `_media_image`seem to be switched accidently.
- It expects all images being in the `var/import/` folder.
- It expects the ID of the attribute `media_gallery` to be 88